# Deriving the Lorentz Factor from the Spacetime Diagram in Minkowski's "Space and Time"

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, mathematics

I'm reading Minkowski's paper on relativity *Space and Time*, and I'm stuck here:

> If $\frac{dx}{dt}$ for the second strip is equal to $v$, an easy calculation gives $OD' = OC \sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$.

He's referring to the following figure:

[image]

where $OA = 1/c$, $OC = 1$; furthermore, $PP=l \cdot OC$; $Q'Q'=l \cdot OC'$, and $QQ = l \cdot OD$, and where $l$ is length of the object whose strips are shown in the figure. He calls $OC$ measuring unit on the $x$-axis.

**Problem:** How can I show that $OD' = OC \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ with "an easy calculation"? I need a hint on this. What I tried is a lengthy calculation and to no avail. The equation of the hyperbola is $c^2t^2-x^2=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses analytic geometry (since it's probably too early to use hyperbolic trigonometry [involving rapidity]).

Note that C and C' lie on the hyperbola $(ct)^2-x^2=-1$ [not drawn].
The tangent at C' is parallel to the worldline along t'.
You can write the equation of the tangent line through C': $\left(\displaystyle\frac{v}{c}\right)(t-C'_t)=(x-C'_x)$.
Event D is the event that is simultaneous with O, according to the observer along t.
So, you seek the value of x when t=0 along the line D'C'.

Comment: The slope I get for this line, by differentiating $t=\frac{1}{c}(x^2-1)^{1/2}$ with respect to $x$ is $1/v = \frac{x}{c\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Comment: I have been able to show that $OD' = C_x'(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}).$